How to resolve error in simple "Ajax Autocomplete for jQuery" deployment?
I am trying to build an autocomplete search function on an application based on the "Ajax Autocomplete for jQuery" found here: https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete.
I'm using jQuery v3.4.1
The code to initialise it is very simple and it initialises fine:
$('#siteSearch').devbridgeAutocomplete({
    paramName: 'q',
    serviceUrl: '/ajax-autocomplete-search'

});

When I enter characters in to my input field, an AJAX http request is sent and a http response is returned as expected.
The http response is correctly formatted JSON as per the docs:
{"suggestions": [{"id":"166","domain_name":"google.com"},{"id":"167","domain_name":"facebook.com"}]}
Frustringly at this point, I get a lengthy error I simply don't undestand.
If I enter one letter, I get the following JavaScript error in the console after the JSON response is returned:
jquery.autocomplete.min.js:142 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
    at _formatResult (jquery.autocomplete.min.js:142:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (jquery.autocomplete.min.js:704:25)
    at Function.each (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2:2861)
    at Autocomplete.suggest (jquery.autocomplete.min.js:693:19)
    at Autocomplete.processResponse (jquery.autocomplete.min.js:857:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (jquery.autocomplete.min.js:610:34)
    at i (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2:27151)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2:27914)
    at z (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:4:12059)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:4:15619)

Bizarrely if I enter two letters, I get slightly different error once the JSON is returned:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')
    at Object.<anonymous> (jquery.autocomplete.min.js:789:55)
    at Function.each (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2:2861)
    at Autocomplete.findBestHint (jquery.autocomplete.min.js:788:19)
    at Autocomplete.onKeyUp (jquery.autocomplete.min.js:467:26)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (jquery.autocomplete.min.js:224:26)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:3:7537)
    at r.handle (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:3:5620)

I've tried redownloading the jquery library, I've tried going up to the latest jQuery version (3.7.1) and an older one (2.2.4) to see if either help and no luck.
I've tried stripping all other javascript out of the project except for jquery and the autocomplete plugin.

Finally figured this out, my JSON format - while valid - wasn't using the specific value names defined by the plugin (this worked fine for about 2 years so I can only assume an update broke it and I didn't notice).
